# Matlab: How to print multiple variables to one line when the number of variables is unknown?

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a matlab code to convert decimal integers into binary. My code seems to work fine, but I am looking for a way to make the output display nicer. I'd like it to all print on one line with d(1) as the rightmost digit. I have found several threads on printing multiple variables to one line, but only for codes where the exact variables being printed are known in advance. Here is the relevant code.

```
while base10 > 0

    %set the binary digits
    if mod(base10, 2) == 1;
        d(i) = 1;
    end

    if mod(base10, 2) == 0;
        d(i) = 0;
    end

    %divide by 2
    base10 = floor(base10/2);
    i = i + 1;

end

while j < (i)
    disp(d(j));
    j = j +1;
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options. First of all, to make `d(1)` the right-most digit, just flip your array around prior to displaying it.

```
data_to_display = flip(d)
```

Then to display it, you can use MATLAB's builtin `disp` which will show all array elements with some padding in between them

```
disp(data_to_display)
%   0   1   0   1   0   1
```

Or you can use `fprintf` to print each digit without a space between them. `fprintf` will use the format specifier that you provide and apply it to *each element of the array automatically*.

```
fprintf('%d', data_to_display)
fprintf('\n')    % Print an explicit newline

% 010101
```

Also, unless you're doing this conversion as a learning exercise, you could benefit by using the built-in for converting decimal numbers to their binary representation, [`dec2bin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html)